# Generating an xls file from an xml file

Tags: java, xml, xls

I am using the below command to convert an xml file to an excel file, but I could not generate the xls file, please advise how to do that?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Workbook;

//import nl.fountain.xelem.excel.Workbook;
import nl.fountain.xelem.lex.ExcelReader;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlToXls11 {
    public void XML() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
    {
        ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader();
        Workbook xlWorkbook = (Workbook) reader.getWorkbook("c:/book.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: you read the xml-file, please show us the code that saves the xls-file

Comment: Actually that is what I am looking for "the code that save the xls file"

Comment: have you tried the XSerializer?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the XSerializer?

```
public void writeExcelXmlFile(String fileNameIn, String fileNameOut){
XLDocument xldoc = new XLDocument(fileNameIn);
OutputStream out;
try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileNameOut));
    new XSerializer().serialize(xldoc.getDocument(), out);
    out.close();    
} catch (XelemException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I guess that it's not possible to write the old xls-binary format with this library.
have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177870/how-can-i-read-or-write-xls-files-using-java